# How to switch sites in different servers

Tags: ftp, backup, hosting

I have the following problem: If I have one website and the server drops, I can configure an backup website? Example: www.exemplesite.com goes offline because of techinical issues, so www.exemplesite2.com goes online, so my users don't have to wait until the first site goes online?

I want something like If> the site 1 goes down Then> the site 2 goes online until site 1 is down When the site 1 comes back to work, I put site 2 down again If I'm not being clear, I'm sorry, my english is very poor

Comment: #1, Add that comment to your post via the "edit" button.  #2, look into load balancers, this is a common problem that a lot of larger websites deal with so it is 100% possible.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look out. So its "load balancers", right?

Comment: Yes.  Also look into "failovers"

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but if you have a load-balancer, you can have two servers points to the same domain regardless if one is down or not. If one goes down, the second server will take all the traffic, and you're not wasting a server because if they are both up, they'll both be processing traffic and improving performance and response time for your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy another domain and put the exact same code in ? and then make it private and if it goes down you can unprivate it ?

Comment: Kind of. 

I want the more or less the following

If> the site 1 goes down
Then> the site 2 goes online until site 1 is down

When the site 1 comes back to work, I put site 2 down again

If I'm not being clear, I'm sorry, my english is very poor

Comment: Yes i understand, But then if you would have a second domain people wouldn't know where to go since they don't know you have a second domain